# startElement and endElement variable are holding 0 and 50 regardless of the input given to them in derived classes

Tags: java, polymorphism

At where I'm missing the link to parent and children class as the startElement and endElement of parent class variables are holding( 0 and 50 )respectively in both the ChildOne and ChildTwo classes regardless of input given to them.

eg: when startElement=20,endElement=100 the filter methods in both classes should return the values in the interval[20,100] but getting values in range [0,50]

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
            /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            int startElement = scan.nextInt();
            int endElement=scan.nextInt();
            Parent a;
            a = new ChildOne();
            System.out.println(a.filter(startElement,endElement));
    
            a = new ChildTwo();
            System.out.println(a.filter(startElement,endElement));
    }
}





class Parent {
    public int startElement;
    public int endElement;
    
    
    public String filter(int startElement,int endElement)
    {
        return null;
    }
    Parent(int startElement,int endElement){
      this.startElement=startElement;
      this.endElement=endElement;
    }
    
}


class ChildOne extends Parent{
    public String filter(int StartElement,int endElement){
      ArrayList<Integer> arr= new ArrayList<Integer>();
      int flag=0;
      System.out.println("input "+startElement +endElement);
        for(int i=startElement;i<=endElement;i++){
            if (i == 1 || i == 0){
                continue;
            }
            flag = 1;
            for(int j=2;j<=i/2;j++){
                if(i%j==0){
                    flag=0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(flag==1){
                arr.add(i);
                
            }
        }
         String str="";
        for(Integer value:arr){
          String s=String.valueOf(value);
          str+=s+' ';
          
        }
        return str;
        
    }
    
}

class ChildTwo extends Parent {
  
    public String filter(int StartElement,int endElement)
    {
       ArrayList<Integer> arr= new ArrayList<Integer>();
       System.out.println("input "+startElement +" "+endElement);
       for(int i=StartElement;i<=endElement;i++)
       {
        int num=i,sum=0,rem;
         while(sum!=1 && sum!=4)
           {
              sum=0;
              while(num!=0)
              {
                  rem=num%10;
                  sum+=(rem*rem);
                  num/=10;
              }
              num=sum;
          }
        if(sum==1){
          arr.add(i);
        } 
                  
     }
    String str="";
    for(Integer value:arr){
       String s=String.valueOf(value);
          str+=s+' ';
      }
      
    return str;
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Presumably, the two child classes should have different results.  They appear to be doing some random math operations.  Can you describe your input, output, and expected output more specifically?  Does it work for some inputs and not others?

Comment: That code shouldn't even compile as you haven't defined a default constructor for your child classes and java won't be able to auto-generate one because your parent class does not have a default constructor. Apart from that in your filter methods you ignore the passed `int StartElement` parameter and instead use the field `startElement` from the parent, which will probably still be 0 as you haven't initialized it. Capitalization is important in java.